# A tricky running problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

> Tom starts running towards a park which is at $800$m from him at speed
>   $20$ m/s.  Kate who starts running with Tom at $25$ m/s goes back and
>   forth between park and Tom until Tom reaches the park.
>
> Find total distance covered  by Kate.

I calculated the sum until Tom and Kate meet each other the second time, and I get the total distance covered by Kate until that time to be $800+88.9+88.9$.

However after that the calculations become too complex. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I did the sum until Tom and Kate meet each other the second time so I get total distance covered by Kate until that to be 800+88.9+88.9. However after that the calculations become too complex is there any other way to do this

Comment: Easier: How long does Tom run? How long does Kate run?

Comment: Tom runs for 40 s so does that mean Kate covers 25 *40 = 1000 m Is it that simple!! Please tell me if I am doing it right

Comment: This is a very similar problem to the famous fly puzzle. See here http://www.primepuzzle.com/leeslightest/howfar.html

Comment: 1000 meters in 40 seconds has got to be a new world record.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is that it doesn't matter "where" Kate runs ; we only want to know the distance she runs, and since we know her speed it suffices to know how long she's been running. Since she runs as long as Tom does, we only need to look at Tom's speed and distance. The solution with the geometric series is uselessly over-descriptive but correct too.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Assuming that her speed is constant, with no slowing down or speeding up when she changes direction.

Comment: @MattClarke : That's the dream. Welcome to physics, where dreams are assumed.

Answer (score 2):

$$800\frac{25}{20}=1000$$
Kate ran for the same lapse of time as Tom.

Comment: In other words, you don't need to know the time. After *any* amount of time, Kate has run $25$% ($25/20=1.25 => 25$%) further than Tom.